# No implementation found for boolean

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call the function but I get the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for
>   boolean com.example.rosaa.ftp.FTPClient.ftpIsConnected() (tried
>   Java_com_example_rosaa_ftp_FTPClient_ftpIsConnected and
>   Java_com_example_rosaa_ftp_FTPClient_ftpIsConnected__)
>           at com.example.rosaa.ftp.FTPClient.ftpIsConnected(Native Method)
>           at com.example.rosaa.ftp.FTPClient.isConnected(FTPClient.java:227)
>           at com.example.rosaa.myapplication.tasks.CheckDroneNetworkAvailabilityTask.doInBackground(CheckDroneNetworkAvailabilityTask.java:86)

here is the function

```
private native boolean ftpIsConnected();
```

function in jni

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_com_example_rosaa_ftp_FTPClient_ftpIsConnected(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    _ftp_t* ftp = get_ftp_handle(env, obj);

    if (ftp != NULL) {
        return (ftp->connected>0?TRUE:FALSE);
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to `System.loadLibrary`?

Answer (score -1):

You need to give the function an implementation that returns a boolean.

```
private native boolean ftpIsConnected() {
    ///Some logic will eventually go here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it can not "native methods cannot hace a body"

Comment: Are you inside an interface class. If so you can't create implementations of functions.

Comment: You will need to create a class that implements that interface. Then you will need to to add function body and call it from an instance of that class.

Comment: Note the `native` keyword. Such functions do not have a Java implementation. The implementation will be made in native code (e.g. C or C++).